# RejectedExecutionException not thrown immediately?

Tags: java

I have an executor that runs some runnables:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                    5, 
                    15, 
                    15000, 
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                    new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100)
                );

            try{
                for(int i = 0; i<=300; i++){
                        Logger.info("Queue size:{}", pool.getQueue().size());
                        pool.execute(new Runnable(){
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                              object.method()
                            }               
                        });
                }
            }
            catch(RejectedExecutionException e){
                Logger.error(e.getMessage());
            }
```

However, the queue is at 100 through several iterations before the RejectedExecutionException is thrown. The output is "Queue Size:100" about 11 times before the exception is thrown. Looking at documentation, that exception should be thrown when the queue size reaches its limit. Any ideas why it doesn't throw the exception immediately?

EDIT: Also meant to say that I'm sleeping the thread created in run() for a few seconds for testing so that the queue will back up.

Comment: Maybe one of the queued tasks gets finished just between retrieving the queue's size and adding the new one?

Comment: Could be caused by that executor tries to start a new thread at first, only when all threads, up to max nr of threads, are busy, rejection is produced. See comments in `ThreadPoolExecutor#execute(Runnable)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. The issue was that I have a maxPoolSize set at 15, with a corePool of 5. When the 5 are busy, tasks are added to the queue. When the queue fills up, more threads (up to the maxPoolSize) are created. So my queue was still full and then the threads created. I changed

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                5, 
                15, 
                15000, 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100)
            );
```

to:

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(
                15, 
                15, 
                15000, 
                TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, 
                new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(100)
            );
```

and the exception was thrown correctly.